# django: how to make query be not lazy executed?

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, query-optimization

I have problem with query lazy execution in my custom Manager method. In it i want to separate query by model CharField choices and return dict[choice, QuerySet].

model.py part:

```py
...

PRODUCT_STATUS = [
    ('pn', 'Запланировано'),
    ('ga', 'В процессе (Ознакомляюсь)'),
    ('rv', 'Повтор'),
    ('ac', 'Завершено'),
    ('ab', 'Брошено'),
    ('pp', 'Отложено'),
]


class ExtendedManager(models.Manager):
    def separated_by_status(self, product_type):
        query = super().get_queryset().all()
        dict_ = {}
        for status in PRODUCT_STATUS:
            dict_.update({status[1]: query.filter(status=status[0]).all()})
        return dict_

...
```

views.py part with manager use:

```py
...

class ProductListView(ContextMixin, View):
    template_name = 'myList/myList.html'

    def get(self, request: HttpRequest, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> HttpResponse:
        product = kwargs.get('product')
        if product not in {'film', 'game', 'series', 'book'}:
            raise Http404
        context = self.get_context_data()
        context['title'] = f'Список {product}'
        context['dict_queryset'] = Product.objects.separated_by_status(product)
        
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

...
```

django debug toolbar result:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVx1M.png)

The problem is that the query is lazy executed in the manager, but in templates it is already fully executed for each PRODUCT_STATUS element separately. How cat it be optimized to execute 1 time?

I'm very sorry if I use the term "lazy" incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the laziness, the problem is that you make a `QuerySet` *per* `PRODUCT_STATUS`.

You can make such dictionary with a single pass with the [**`groupby`** function [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) of the [**`itertools`** module [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

class ExtendedManager(models.Manager):
    def separated_by_status(self, product_type):
        query = super().get_queryset().order_by('status')
        dict_ = {
            k: list(vs)
            for k, vs in groupby(query, attrgetter('status'))
        }
        return {
            status1: dict_.get(status0, [])
            for status0, status1 in PRODUCT_STATUS
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, it is the solution. As I understand, every time I use `.all()`, `.filter()` etc., it makes new QuerySet? So, to avoid it, I should filter query with internal tools of Python itself?

Comment: @ALittleMoron: it will indeed make a new queryset, and when necessary evaluate it. If you need to group data, it is therefore better to retrieve all data with a single query, and do the grouping at the Django/Python layer. But filtering should be done as much as possible by the database.